# multiple where condition in yii2

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2

Hi, my problem is simple i want to add multiple where condition on yii2 Query bulder, but i don't know what doing.

my code like that

```
public function searchForTrip($params, $extraParams, $filter) {
    $query = Boatinformation::find()
        ->where(['what_island' => $params['BoatinformationSearch']['what_island']])
        ->all();

    if(isset($filter)) {
        foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
            ->andFilterWhere([$value => 1])
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
```

this is not working

please someone help me

Comment: Use [andWhere()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#andWhere%28%29-detail)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write something like

```
public function searchForTrip($params, $extraParams, $filter) {
$query = Boatinformation::find()
    ->where(['what_island' => $params['BoatinformationSearch']['what_island']])

if(isset($filter)) {
    foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {
        $query->andFilterWhere([$value => 1])
    }
}

return $query;
}
```

`$query->andFilterWhere()` add where condition if $value exist,

`$query->andWhere()` add where condition always

and if you want to return objects instead of query you should return `$query->all();`

Comment: Wow!! it is a perfect solution for my code. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

You can do in several way  and you can found an useful guide in this doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

you can use string format specifying the condition as a string :

```
 $query->where('your_field1 =1 and your_field2 = 2');
```

You can use hash format and

```
$query->where([
  'your_field1' => 10,
  'your_field2' => null,
  'your_field3' => [4, 8, 15],
]);
```

You can use operator format

```
 $query->where(['and' , 'your_field1', 10, ]);
```

and you can also use

```
 andWhere('your_field'=> $your_value ),
```

Comment: @johnsnails  if all the condion are in AND  .. you could use  the hash format .. but depend  of what you really mean ..  try add  a proper data and code sample  and eventually the error you have  --

Comment: This worked for me: $query->where([
  'your_field1' => 10,
  'your_field2' => null,
  'your_field3' => [4, 8, 15],
]);